# Python: Sort by Nested Dictionary Value (no categories)

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I need to sort (descending order) the following by the nested value per person:

```
d={
'BILLY': {'beer': 1, 'socks': 3, 'germs': 2}, 
'JAN': {'mewo': 18, 'towel': 83, 'bee': 27}, 
'NICK': {'shoes': 50, 'hats': 15, 'dogs': 95}
}
```

**Results should be**

BILLY:
socks = 3
germs = 2
beer = 1

JAN:
towel = 83
bee = 27
mewo = 18

NICK:
dogs = 95
shoes = 50
hats = 15

I tried the following, but getting errors:

```
outer_keys = d.keys()
print ("outer keys:")
for outer_key in outer_keys:
    print (outer_key)

print ("*" * 40)
inner_keys = d[outer_key].keys()

for key in inner_keys:
    ordered = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][key])

print(ordered)
```

Comment: What do you mean with descending order? Are Billy, Jan, etc. sorted themselves in ascending order (why is Billy before Jan), or is this just "random"?

Comment: None of your data points have any keys in common. What value specifically are you trying to sort by?

Comment: @C.Nivs: I'm not sure if the persons have to be sorted, based on the same output, only the items *per* person are sorted in descending order.

Comment: ah, good catch, didn't think of that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to iterate over the subdictionaries (stored in the values) as well, you need a nested loop. So the "skeleton" looks like:

```
for k, subdic in d.items():
    print(k)
    # ...
    print()
```

Dictionaries themselves are *unordered*. We need a datastructure that maintains order, like for example a list. We can sort the items by taking the *value* item of a tuple. So for a *subdictionary*, we can sort it like:

```
sorted(subdic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Then we need to iterate over these items as well, and print these, like:

```
for subk, v in sorted(subdic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(f'{subk} = {v}')
```

So we can combine the two in:

```
for k, subdic in d.items():
    print(k)
    for subk, v in sorted(subdic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        print(f'{subk} = {v}')
    print()
```

Comment: **YES!!! THANK YOU** This worked. And thank you for the step-by-step explanation as well! Willem, thank you!